# structure and pointers concept

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I tried linked list programming by structur and pointers.passing parameters in functions and accessing structure members and I got below error please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

    enter code here

 struct node {

    int32_t data;
    struct node *next;
};


void 
     SLL_insert_beg(      struct node *head_lst

                            ){
    int32_t num_lst; 
    struct node *temp_lst,*new_lst;      //intialising  local variable. 
    new_lst = ( struct node* )malloc( sizeof(struct node) );   //Allocating dynamic memory for node new.
    printf(" Enter data: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_lst );
    new_lst->data = num_lst;                   //inserting data into the datafield in node new.

    if(head_lst == NULL)  {                    //Condition to check list is empty in SLL_insert_beg() function.

        new_lst->next = NULL;                  //Making pointer field to point null in node new. 
        head_lst = new_lst;                    //Making new node as head node.

     } else {

        new_lst->next = head_lst;              //pointer field in new node points to the head node.
        head_lst = new_lst;                    //Making new node as head node. 
    }
}

void SLL_display(     struct node *head_lst    


                                                  ) {

        struct node *temp_lst,*new_lst;
        int32_t i_lst = 1 ;                      //intialising  local variable.
    if( head_lst == NULL ) {                 //Condition to check list is empty in  SLL_display() function.

          printf( " List is empty!! " );

    } else {

        temp_lst = head_lst;                 //Making head node as temp node.
        printf( "\nThe linked list is:\n " );
        printf( " Elements: " );
                                             /*Below loop used to print all elements 
                                               in single linked list*/
        while( temp_lst != NULL ) {  

            printf( "%d-> ", temp_lst->data );
            temp_lst = temp_lst->next;       //Making  temp next node as  temp node.
        }
        printf( "NULL\n " );
        printf( " Position: " );

        temp_lst = head_lst;                 //Making head node as temp node.
                                             /*Below loop used to print no.of positions 
                                               in single linked list*/
        while( temp_lst != NULL ) {

            printf( "%d    " , i_lst );
           i_lst = i_lst + 1;                //Incrementing variable 'i_lst' once.
            temp_lst = temp_lst->next;       //Making  temp next node as  temp node.
        }

    }

 }                              
void main(void) {                                                  //sll_program(void) {

    int32_t data;
    int32_t SL_ch; //Intialised a variable  used to choose the option in the below menu.
   struct node *head_lst=NULL;
    struct node *temp_lst,*new_lst;
     while( 1 ) {

                 printf(" \n\nSingly Linked List(SLL)");
                 printf(" \n1.Insert beg     \
                          \n2.diplay  \
                           \n3.exit     "   );
                 printf("\nEnter your choice(1-4):");
                 scanf("%d",&SL_ch);
       switch(SL_ch) {

                     case 1:                  //If choice is 1 calls insert at beginning function.
                             SLL_insert_beg(    &head_lst
                                                              );
                             break;
                     case 2: 
                          SLL_display(           &head_lst



                                                             );                   //If choice is 2 calls the display function.
                                    break;
                      case 3: 
                                 return;
                    default: 
                               printf( "Please give the right choice!!" );              

       }
     }
}
```

AFTER COMPILATION THIS IS THE ERROR for my code

> main.c: In function 'main':
>
> main.c:91:63: warning: passing argument 1 of 'SLL_insert_beg' from
>   incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   main.c:12:6: note: expected 'struct node *' but argument is of type
>   'struct node **'
>         SLL_insert_beg(      struct node *head_lst                                                                                                          main.c:98:62: warning: passing argument 1 of 'SLL_display' from
>   incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   );                   //If choice is 2 calls the display function.
>
> main.c:34:6: note: expected 'struct node *' but argument is of type
>   'struct node **'
>   void SLL_display(     struct node *head_lst

Comment: Please reduce your included code to a minimal example. So we can offer advice.

Comment: What is unclear to you with the error messages the compiler issues?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the declaration is `SLL_insert_beg(struct node *head_lst);` and the invocation is `SLL_insert_beg(&head_lst);` - all this while `head_lst` is declared as a pointer to `struct node` (`struct node *head_lst=NULL`). This causes `&head_lst` to be a pointer to a pointer to `struct node`.

In other words, as the compiler warned: `expected 'struct node *' but argument is of type 'struct node **'`

Either change the function's declaration, or change the invocation.

Comment: You should change the declaration, as in SLL_insert_beg() you want to change the value of head_lst. After that, you will also need to change the function's code to manage a "pointer to pointer" (well, struct node **, a pointer to a pointer pointing to a struct node).

Comment: please could you give brief explanation in code. I am unable to understand. where should I change the  code. thanks for paintence rplyyy